# C# displaying error 'Delegate 'System.Func<...>' does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am calling:

```
        form = new FormFor<Project>()
            .Set(x => x.Name, "hi");
```

where Project has a field called Name and FormFor's code is:

```
public class FormFor<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    FormCollection form;


    public FormFor()
    {
        form = new FormCollection();
    }

    public FormFor<TEntity> Set(Expression<Func<TEntity>> property, string value)
    {
        form.Add(property.PropertyName(), value);

        return this;
    }
}
```

but it keeps telling me `Delegate 'System.Func<ProjectSupport.Core.Domain.Project>' does not take 1 arguments` and I am unsure why. Could anyone shed some light on it for me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's trying to convert this lambda expression:

```
x => x.Name
```

into an `Expression<Func<TEntity>>`.

Let's ignore the expression tree bit for the moment - the delegate type `Func<TEntity>` represents a delegate which takes no arguments, and returns a `TEntity`. Your lambda expression `x => x.Name` clearly *is* expecting a parameter (`x`). I suspect you want

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, string>>
```

or something similar, but it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Type of expression "x => x.Name" is not `Expression<Func<TEntity>>`, but `Expression<Func<TEntity, string>>`. I suppose, you should change declaration of Set method:

```
public FormFor<TEntity> Set<V>(Expression<Func<TEntity, V>> property, string value)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Func<TEntity>` is a delegate taking zero parameters and returns an object of type `TEntity`. You are trying to supply an `x` and return nothing.